# How to save double quotes in XML header using QDomDocument

Tags: xml, qt, qdomdocument

Before opening XML document the header was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

But after using QDomDocument

```
if (!file.open((QIODevice::ReadOnly)))
{
    return;
}

QDomDocument document;
if (!document.setContent(&file))
{
    return;
}

file.close();

if (!file.open(QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    return;
}

QTextStream out(&file);
document.save(out, 2);
file.close();

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
```

I know what xml standart allows to use single quotes. But I need to use double quotes.

Comment: What is `aterer`? You need to fix your spelling, like `standard`, etc. More importantly, would you be able to explain why you need double quotes?

Comment: @LászlóPapp Sorry, I corrected mistake instead of 'aterer' I use 'after'. Because parser in my company can not handlung single quotes

Comment: It is still unclear to me what exactly you mean by after? You do not show the code that generates the output with `'`. Can you show that, please?

Comment: @LászlóPapp I corrected my example. Please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use [QXmlStreamWriter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qxmlstreamwriter.html) which prefers double quotes, or you could postprocess the [string representation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qdomdocument.html#toString) of you document before streaming. For example:

```
out << document.toString(2).replace('\'', '\"');
```

Alternatively, you could also submit a feature request on the [Qt issue tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTWEBSITE-1060?jql=) to add some configuration to [QDomDocument](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qdomdocument.html) and see whether the Qt developers think.